# git - Merge a series of commits as one commit

Tags: git, merge

I have a question about how to merge my changes from one branch to another. Here's the scheme of things:

There are three branches: Master(M), Feature(F) and Development(D)

D was created off M before F was created, again off M. Ideally, D should've been created from F, with the hierarchy:

```
        M
        |
        |
        F
        |
        |
        D
```

M is always update to date with changes from other commits.

Now on my D branch, the changes comprise of a series of commits which I'd like to merge to F as one commit. How do I do that? This in turn would be merged to M later on.

Please note that D and F may be branched off different commits in M.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now on my D branch, the changes comprise of a series of commits which I'd like to merge to F as one commit

```
git checkout F
git merge --squash D
git commit
```

Comment: When I do a `git log`, the output shows the list of commits that were squashed together. Is there a way to do it so only the new commit ID with the comment as 'merge' would be displayed?

Comment: Yes, use `git commit -m <message>`. An empty `git commit` here uses the default from `merge --squash`, which is a concatenated list of the branch commits.

Comment: Very neat, also probably the safest way to do it since no rebase is involved.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `git rebase` command. For the simple case, do

```
git checkout D
git rebase F
```

Alternatively, do

```
git rebase D F
```

This will not squash into a single commit. To do that, probably the least error-prone option will be to do an interactive commit:

```
git checkout D
git rebase -i F
```

This will show an editor with the commits in `D` that are going to be rebased. It will look something like this:

```
pick 293a24d Some commit message
pick a015bbe Some commit message
pick e19f4fa Some commit message
pick 40ae959 Some commit message
pick fba6b72 Some commit message

# Rebase 419206d..fba6b72 onto de95063
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Follow the instructions and change all but the first line to start with `squash` instead of `pick`. This will give you the option to merge the messages once you save and exit your editor.

Alternatively, you can change the fits `pick` to `reword` and the remaining ones to `fixup`. This will only show you the first commit message. This option is simpler if you want to completely throw away all the old commit messages.

Finally, if you are feeling very adventurous, you can automatically filter the commit list, bypassing the first interactive part of the rebase:

```
EDITOR='sed -i -e "2,$s/pick/squash/"' git rebase -i F
```

This will automatically change `pick` to `squash` on all lines starting with the second line by filtering the editor file through `sed` instead of your usual interactive editor.

Comment: Rebasing is a powerful tool that can leave you in a weird state if you’re not careful. If you’re new to the command, it’s wise to backup your repo before proceeding.

Comment: -1; this does not do what OP is asking for. Yes, he mentions that D should be branched off F rather than M, but that's not his question; he wants to squash commits into one commit, which is not what a simple rebase will do.

Comment: @JoeChrysler I think this is bad advice. Repos should be backed-up regardless of source control. Comments like this just scare people away from using `git`. How can asker realistically mess up his repo in a way that `git rebase --abort` or `git checkout`/`git reset` could not fix?

Comment: @RJFalconer. You are absolutely right. I hope I have fixed to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

> Now on my D branch, the changes comprise of a series of commits which I'd like to merge to F as one commit. How do I do that?

```
git checkout D
git rebase -i F       # pick "squash" for every commit

git checkout F
git merge D
```

See http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html for a good example (but it's really not very complicated, `git help rebase` should be enough as well). Basically, you edit the file provided to you by `git rebase -i` and enter "squash" on all lines.

> This in turn would be merged to M later on.

```
git checkout M
git merge F
```